# MaterialApp Widget's title Property Not Working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-virtual-device

I am an absolute beginner to Flutter !

[image]

**Picture# 1 : Reference from tutorial.**

[image]

**Picture# 2 : My implementation.**

***Virtual Device: Nexus_5X_API_28
Android: 9.0***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the same emulator in both examples? 
The title in MaterialApp Widget isn't the title you will see in the Application Bar.

> used by the device to identify the app

as documentation says.

So Maybe it is how the device displays 'running applications menu'.

---

If you want to display the appBar you need to use Scaffold

```
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text("text"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: If title Text(‘My app’); is showing the title then what the **title: ‘App’** is showing. ?

Comment: MaterialApp- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/title.html

AppBar- https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_for_web/latest/material/AppBar-class.html

Comment: It's the name displayed when the user presses the "recent apps" button on Android. It's optional, it doesn't affect you app. I also think in ios it hasn't any affect. I will say that you can think about it (not exactly) like HTML title tag  `<title>Name</title>`.  Hope it helps